# Quadratic Forms in $n$ dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

In my linear algebra high school textbook, there is a 'Project' that extends geometrical ideas to '$n$-dimensional space'.

I have no idea what to do or where to begin for this question.

> Show that the following four-dimensional 'surface' is bounded, and find the smallest four-dimensional 'spherical' region within which the surface lies: $$\frac{3}{2}x^2 + \frac{3}{2}y^2 + \frac{7}{2}z^2 + \frac{7}{2}t^2 -xy +zt=1$$

Edit: I had previously asked a question about forming the symmetric matrix for a quadratic form    of 4 variables and how to generalise that but that has been resolved now after a prompt by Hurkyl's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Hurkyl's comment, your quadratic form can be represented by the matrix
$$
\frac 12
\pmatrix{
3&-1&0&0\\
-1&3&0&0\\
0&0&7&1\\
0&0&1&7
}
$$
In order to prove that it is bounded, you should show that this matrix is positive definite. Finding the sphere containing this surface can be related to the [eigenvalues of this matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't noticed, there is an equality

$$\begin{align}\left[\begin{matrix}x&y&z&t\end{matrix}\right] &\left[
\begin{matrix}6 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 3 & 1 & -1 \\ 1&1&3&-1 \\ -1&-1&-1&6 \end{matrix}
\right] \left[ \begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ t \end{matrix} \right]
\\ \\&=
6x^2 + 3y^2 + 3z^2 + 6t^2
\\&\quad + 2 xy + 2xz + 2yz - 2xt - 2yt - 2zt
\end{align}$$

which can be seen by computing the matrix product. Actually working through the calculation should make it clear how a homogeneous quadratic form corresponds to a symmetric matrix.

Comment: My guess for a generalisation would be this: Set up an $n x n$ matrix where $n$ is the number of variables. First place the coefficients of the square of the variables along the diagonal of the matrix. Next we have to determine in which entries the coefficient of $x_ix_j$ goes, where the $x_j^2$ coefficient is lower down the diagonal. To do this draw a vertical  line straight down from the entry corresponding to $x_i^2$ and a horizontal line across from the entry of $x_j^2$. The intersection of these two lines is where the entry for $x_ix_j$ goes. Reflect these entries in the diagonal.